# I am struggling (again) to figure out how to replace characters in strings using substrings

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am struggling (again) to figure out how to replace characters in strings using substrings.
So what I am trying to do is input a sentence into JOptionPane and then replace the first word of that sentence with asterisks using substrings. I have this so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Alternate
{
public static void main (String[] args)

   {
     String myName;
   myName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a sentence");
   String ast= "**********";
   String words= myName.indexOf(" ");
```

I know somehow you can use indexOf in there, I just can't put the pieces together, any help would be great thanks.

Comment: which output do you have?

Comment: your code is incomplete, post complete code, with what the output you get is and what you expect

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't replace anything in the `inline` you have to create new String objects or call something like `.replaceFirst()` which returns a new `String` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement. For a *word* the [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) would be:  `"\\w+"`

```
String str = "aWord bWord";     
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("\\w+", "*****"));
```

**Output:**

```
***** bWord
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips to you get started (I won't outline the full solution).

That call to `indexOf` returns the index of the first space. Presumably, the first word is the only part of the string before that index. How might you use that call to

1. Figure out how long the first word was
2. Get the substring starting at the first space.

Once you figure out those steps, you're most of the way there.